# How to clear/disable cookies/cache in twitter and facebook SDK on signin/signout in android

Tags: android, twitter, facebook-android-sdk

Am using Twitter SDK and Facebook SDK for login purpose. I can able to sign in on both social login. But some times am getting error from twitter like

> 01-09 21:16:46.806 com.intentfilter.android W/Twitter: Authorize already in progress
>
> 01-09 21:16:46.807 com.intentfilter.android E/Twitter: Authorization completed with an error 
>   com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterAuthException: Authorize failed.

But in facebook i didn't face this kind of issue.
My doubt is, there is anyway to clear cookies/cache on internal browser in android ? or else how to disable/clear cookies/cache on twitter SDK. If there is no way, how to redirect end user to the twitter login page every time which means user should enter their credentials every time instead store cache in android browser

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this, to remove all cookies

```
 CookieSyncManager.createInstance(className.this);
 CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
 cookieManager.removeAllCookie();
```

Hope, it works for you!!!

Comment: Actually i have tried this. It's cleared cookies/cache and ask users to enter the twitter credentials for each time login. But this is not actual fix. still am facing error. Let's say, i am clicking facebook icon, its redirect to facebook page for conform identity. Once confirm its come back to app's login page. in between this time, if we click twitter button, its starting its process, meanwhile from background process, server communication done and moving to home page. From app user sign out and try to sign in with twitter login am facing the above issue